# Transfer all data from my account to another in the same Azure subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to transfer all data (websites, blob, databases) from my account to another in the same Azure subscription, because I need to close my account and I can't miss this data.
There's a way to perform this without to contact Microsoft Support?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `from my account to another in the same Azure subscription`? Normally I have seen folks want to move data from one subscription to another one (say from Dev Subscription to Prod Subscription).

Comment: I've two account under the same subscription, because I've join the BizSpark Program.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your Azure Subscription you have 2 Microsoft accounts using which you login. Now you want to close one of the login account but wanted to make sure that you can still access the data when you login using other account. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do the data transfer as the subscription remains the same. What you would need to do is `transfer account ownership`.

For instructions on changing the account ownership from one account to another, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn736055.aspx.

In short, you will need to create a support request.