# How to publish a Web Application to another persons azure subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I currently have a Web Application and SQL Database instance published on my own personal Azure trial subscription. However the app is now finished and I want to hand ownership over to the person I am creating it for. So I want to publish it to his Azure subscription, so he can look after billing, monitor, and have ownership of the application etc.

I asked him to add me as a user to his account, and now I see his company name listed as a 'Directory' from the portals home page (along with my Default Directory, my Web App, and my SQL Database). I don't know how to proceed from here. I want to be able to Publish it from Visual Studio 2013 - then run my code first migrations to create the database, all to a location that his company and not me is responsible for.

Is my approach to this wrong? In a general sense, how do you develop a test application (and test it in Azure) and publish it for someone else on Azure?

The first comment on the question is sort of what I am trying to achieve:
[Transfer all data from my account to another in the same Azure subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341681/transfer-all-data-from-my-account-to-another-in-the-same-azure-subscription)

*"What do you mean by from my account to another in the same Azure subscription? Normally I have seen folks want to move data from one subscription to another one (say from Dev Subscription to Prod Subscription)."*

But if I just transfer the app I wouldn't be able to make changes in VS and re-publish it, for example.

**EDIT**:
I found [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/) on Migrating an enterprise web app to an Azure service. Would it be possible to Publish the app to my local dev machine (with local database), then use the Migration Assistance to move it to Azure? Obviously to do this I would need my clients Microsoft ID and password to log into his subscription which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first want to make sure that the subscription appears in your "Subscription list" in the top right corner and is selected.

I am assuming you have connected your VS with your Azure subscription and are able to publish your app to your subscription from here, and that the new subscription is "missing" from your selection. But now you have been added to a new subscription but have not updated VS. Remove and readd Azure Subscriptions from VS. This should require you to log into Azure, and should pull updated account information.

Now when you Deploy your app, you will be able to select which Subscription you want to deploy it into.

Comment: Yes I have connected VS with my Azure subscription and can publish to my subscription. Is there a way I can confirm through the Azure portal that I have been added to the new subscription? For example - in the Azure Portal, if I click New - Compute - Web App - Quick Create - I cannot see the new subscription under 'App Service Plan'. So I assume I cannot publish to that subscription yet. Could this be an issue where I don't have the right 'Role'?

Comment: Sorry in my orginal post I said top left, meant top right, on manage.windowsazure.com you should see "Subscriptions", when you click this should be a drop down list of all your subs

Comment: Thanks, finally worked out that I hadn't been made a co-administrator on the new subscription. So the "subscriptions" menu you mentioned wasn't showing up.